# How do I create an alias for a command containing single quotes?

Tags: bash, escaping, alias, quoting

To read the header of the fitsfile I use this command in the bash:

```
hexdump -e '"%_ad\t" 80/1 "%_p" "\n"' astlimits.fits  | less
```

Here, the fits file can be downloaded from the website:
http://das.sdss.org/contents/fits/astlimits.fits

Now I tried to create an alias in BASH like this:

```
alias fitsheader='hexdump -e \'"%_ad\t" 80/1 "%_p" "\n"\''
```

But, it didn't work.
What is the correct syntax for this so that the following command works:

```
fitsheader astlimits.fits | less
```

Comment: Please don't add a follow-up question. As @chepner suggests, and is consistent with your symptom, an existing _alias_ definition of `fitsheader` is likely causing the syntax error, because that means that the word `fitsheader` in the function definition is alias-expanded, resulting in something that is not a valid function name. Note that even if your `~/.bashrc` file contains no such alias definition, you'll still run into this problem if you defined the alias _interactively_ and then _reload_ `~/.bashrc` instead of opening a new shell or restarting your terminal.

Comment: Please confirm that the problem is resolved; if not, please remove the follow-on question from this question and post it as a _new_ question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Nesting of single quotes inside a single-quoted string is not supported** in Bash (and other POSIX-compatible shells).

You can, however, **use an [ANSI C-quoted string (`$'...'`)](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting)**, in which `'` can be quoted (escaped) as `\'`.

```
alias fitsheader=$'hexdump -e \'"%_ad\t" 80/1 "%_p" "\n"\''
```

<sup>Note that the `\t` and `\n` will be expanded to a literal tab and newline *up front* by the `$...`, which, however, doesn't make a difference here; when in doubt, double all `\` instances in the original string.</sup>

Generally, though, **consider using a function, as [chepner suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36051010/45375)**, as it avoids the quoting headaches and is extensible.

Comment: one more question, what should be the alias for tcsh for MacOS? alias fitsheader $'hexdump -e \'"%_ad\t" 80/1 "%_p" "\n"\''       doesnot work.

Comment: The value of this site is in _well-defined_ questions and matching answers. While changing the question and asking follow-on questions may be helpful to you personally, it is a distraction to others. Please ask a _new_ question, _specifically_ about a `tcsh` alias (as an aside, I personally cannot help you with that, but I have a tip: for easy cross-shell use, write a _script_ instead.)

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother with an alias; use a function instead.

```
fitsheader () {
    hexdump -e '"%_ad\t" 80/1 "%_p" "\n"' "$1"
}
```

Comment: I tried this code inside ~/.bashrc, it gives following error: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: Are you still defining the alias? If so, remove it; the function definition is being expanded to `hexdump -e ... ()`, which would cause the syntax error.

Comment: i placed above function inside ~/.bashrc and sourced it, but that did not worked, what could be the correct method?

Comment: @BhishanPoudel: What chepner is saying is that the function definition will not work as expected if the name `fitsheader` is already defined as an _alias_ when the function definition is encountered. To rule that out, either place `unalias fitsheader` directly before the function definition, or define your function with `function` (though you'd still need to undefine the alias, as it would take precedence).

Comment: @BhishanPoudel: Perhaps you have _more than 1_ definition of the alias in your file (or in a file sourced by that file). To rule that out, do what I suggested in my previous comment.

Comment: @BhishanPoudel: As I've just commented on the question, perhaps you're _reloading_ `~/.bashrc` instead of opening a new shell. If you've placed `unalias fitsheader` directly before the function definition and it still doesn't work, I suggest asking a _new_ question focused on that problem.

Comment: I restarted the geany now the function suggested by chepner works, Thanks.